# SSL handshake problem on docker using Nginx and Socketio

Tags: node.js, docker, ssl, nginx

I am not expert about server side processes so, I will try to keep my question very simple. I am using Socket.io + Nginx + Vuejs + LetsEncrypt and want to host multiple websites on docker. But i got a problem with socket.io SSL. I have two containers, one is for backend and the other one is for frontend. I can share data from backend to frontend using socket.io with HTTP. However, the problem is to use HTTPS. Because, i have to use files that are keys for certification from LetsEncrypt in backend container to handshake with frontend.

So, How can i reach files from backend container to nginx container? or, what is the best way to communicate to get keys from nginx container? i am so newbee about this. Maybe i am not the right point to achieve this.

> this is nginx compose file

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.1
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
    labels:
      - "com.github.jrcs.letsencrypt_nginx_proxy_companion.nginx_proxy=true"

  dockergen:
    image: jwilder/docker-gen:0.7.3
    container_name: nginx-proxy-gen
    depends_on:
      - nginx
    command: -notify-sighup nginx-proxy -watch -wait 5s:30s /etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./nginx.tmpl:/etc/docker-gen/templates/nginx.tmpl:ro

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-le
    depends_on:
      - nginx
      - dockergen
    environment:
      NGINX_PROXY_CONTAINER: nginx-proxy
      NGINX_DOCKER_GEN_CONTAINER: nginx-proxy-gen
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro

volumes:
  conf:
  vhost:
  html:
  certs:

# Do not forget to 'docker network create nginx-proxy' before launch, and to add '--network nginx-proxy' to proxied containers. 

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

> server.js in backend container

```
var fs = require('fs');
var app = require('express')();
var https   = require('https');
var io = require('socket.io')(https);
var HTTPSOptions = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/cert.pem'), // i have to reach certs files from nginx container
    key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/key.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./certs/chain.pem'),
    requestCert: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
};
HTTPSOptions.agent = new https.Agent(HTTPSOptions);
var httpsServer = https.createServer(HTTPSOptions, app);
io = io.listen(httpsServer, {
    log: false
});
httpsServer.listen(4001, "0.0.0.0",() =>{
  console.log('Listening on Port 4001');
});
```

> added these to nginx config file

```
upstream upstream-nodejs {
        server  0.0.0.0:4001;
}



  }
        location /socket.io/ {
                proxy_pass              http://upstream-nodejs;
                proxy_redirect off;

                proxy_http_version      1.1;

                proxy_set_header        Upgrade                 $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header        Connection              "upgrade";

                proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can anybody help?

Comment: did you find the solution ?